How to add buttons to widgets in smart stack on watchOS 10+
is it possible to add functional buttons to the widgets in the smart stack of the Apple watchOS 10+?
It's similar to the widget that come with the Stopwatch app in watchOS:


Note that when we click the button in the stopwatch widget of the smart stack, it does not switch to the stopwatch app, but directly starts or pauses the stopwatch.
How was this achieved? what views or mechanisms are needed in SwiftUI to accomplish such functionality?
Thanks a lot!!! ;)
